# Custom Listview with two types of rows

Tags: android

I need to create a ListView with two types of list items.

ListView model is below:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: yes..suppose have around 5 record in array..need to display as per above template..please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

may be you should try this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
   if (position % 2 == 0) {
       //inflate your one cell layout
   } else {
       //inflate your two cell layout
   }

   return view;  
}
```

Comment: yes..suppose have around 5 record in array..need to display as per above template.. i have tried with this concept , but success...how can i handle data ..thats current issue?